# Java 9 new docs structure - where are "old" java packages?

Tags: java, javadoc, java-9, java-module

I'm used to access Java SE docs from the following links, from which I can search for packages like java.awt, java.util and so on:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

However, when accessing [similar link for version 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/index.html?overview-summary.html), I could see some module structures which are very different from Java SE docs until version 8. What happened to "old" Java packages?

Comment: what is java-9 modularization?

Comment: The new javadocs have a search box, so just type `java.util` etc. in the search box in top right corner

Comment: Click the module name "java.base" to find a lot of core Java packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java 9, they decided to divide JDK system into small modules. This applies to the source code too, dividing it in several jars smaller than `rt.jar`. You can take a look at:

https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html

Now in the new java 9 javadocs overview you only can view a list of modules. However, if you need a list of packages,  you can obtain it just clicking in the link "ALL PACKAGES" in the right-top corner:

[image]

Comment: You are right, but it isn't exactly the same overview as you had with the previous Java versions (that included a list of packages + description).

Comment: I don't think so, previous overviews had a list of packages+descriptions, but in new java 9 overview you only can see a list of modules, if you click in a module, you can see the list of packages that make up this module.

Comment: You can also access the packages using the search box on top right to query. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/overview-summary.html